# Bash building string

Tags: string, bash, concatenation

I have the following code:

```
streams=("CI" "UI" "QA")
role_text="streams:read:"
result=""

for s in "${streams[@]}"
do
   STREAMID=$(curl -s -u $user:$pass  -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" ${GRAYLOG2_URL}/streams | python /opt/script.py $s)
   curl -s -u $user:$pass -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" ${GRAYLOG2_URL}/streams/${STREAMID}/resume > /dev/null
   result=$result$role_text$STREAMID,
   echo "result: "$result
done

final_result=$(echo $result | sed '$s/.$//')
ROLES=$(curl -u $user:$pass -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" ${GRAYLOG2_URL}/roles 2>/dev/null)
echo "Final result: "$final_result
GRAYLOG2_ROLE='
{
  "name" : "'$role'",
  "description" : "'${role}' role",
  "permissions" : [ "'${final_result}'" ],
  "read_only" : false
}'
```

`${final_result}` should be a string like:

```
"streams:read:582e0b99b9d3230d808cc0d0", "streams:read:582e0b99b9d3230d808cc0d4", "streams:read:582e0b98b9d3230d808cc0cb"
```

Instead, the result I get is:

```
"streams:read:582e0b98b9d3230d808cc0cb,streams:read:582e0b99b9d3230d808cc0d0,streams:read:582e0b99b9d3230d808cc0d4"
```

Which obviously, is not working as it should.

Can anyone tell me how do I get to the needed result?

Thank you very much,
Gabriel

Comment: what makes you think that the quotes and the spaces will be preserved by bash var concatenation? You have to escape them.

Comment: This is as expected. You are printing a string and not an array. Printing an array like this in bash is also not easy. I would print it with escaped characters and do a split in a different language.

Comment: Put all variable references in double-quotes! For example, use `curl -s -u "$user:$pass" ...` and `echo "result: $result"`. I don't know if that's the source of the specific problem, but it's not really worth looking at it in detail until you've done that. BTW, [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) is very handy for doing basic sanity-checking like this.

Comment: To transit just from your current output to expected output, you could append `| sed "s/\,/\",\"/g"`.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was related to the fact that the `${final_result}` should have been created as an array of strings like:

```
"streams:read:582e0b99b9d3230d808cc0d0", "streams:read:582e0b99b9d3230d808cc0d4", "streams:read:582e0b98b9d3230d808cc0cb"
```

but instead, I would get a big string like:

```
"streams:read:582e0b98b9d3230d808cc0cb,streams:read:582e0b99b9d3230d808cc0d0,streams:read:582e0b99b9d3230d808cc0d4"
```

I got help from a colleague and solved the problem like this:

```
 result="$result\"$role_text$STREAMID\""
```

Thank you all for having a look and point me to the right direction.
Gabriel